# Errors while installing terminator terminal, fresh install of kali linux 2017.3 64 bit

Tags: kali-linux

This is a fresh install of kali 2017.3 64 bit on virtual box. I am trying to install the terminator terminal.

```
**This is my sources.list:**

# 

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 $

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 L$

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib





**Attempt to install terminator:**

root@kali:~# apt-get install terminator
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0 python-gi-cairo python-psutil
Suggested packages:
  python-psutil-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 libkeybinder-3.0-0 python-gi-cairo python-psutil
  terminator
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 833 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,337 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:1 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 libkeybinder-3.0-0 amd64 0.3.1-1
  404  Not Found
Err:2 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 amd64 0.3.1-1
  404  Not Found
Err:3 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-gi-cairo amd64 3.24.1-5
  404  Not Found
Err:4 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 python-psutil amd64 5.0.1-1+b1
  404  Not Found
Get:5 http://archive-7.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 terminator all 1.91-1 [363 kB]
Fetched 363 kB in 1s (319 kB/s)    
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/keybinder-3.0/libkeybinder-3.0-0_0.3.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/k/keybinder-3.0/gir1.2-keybinder-3.0_0.3.1-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/pygobject/python-gi-cairo_3.24.1-5_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/p/python-psutil/python-psutil_5.0.1-1+b1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


**Attempt to update:**

root@kali:~# apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive-7.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
Err:1 http://archive-7.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
Fetched 30.5 kB in 0s (34.4 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive-7.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have followed tutorials in regards to updating the keyring and the sources.list file but nothing seems to work. Also, I have tried installing terminator from the source and I get the same errors.

Comment: Please include your error message in the question, not as images.

Comment: Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this link: https://linux-audit.com/how-to-solve-an-expired-key-keyexpired-with-apt/

specifically:
apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys ED444FF07D8D0BF6